# проблема с getsом

Tags: c

Когда пользователь вводит слова и их много эти слова записываются в переменную "b",но в эту переменную умещается только 5 элементов(char b[5];),если пользователь введет больше 5 букв,то выйдет ошибка "was corrupted"(думаю всем известна),так как выходит из предел массива(я могу написать "char b[10000];",туда вместится очень много,но это глупо сами понимаете) .Перейдем к главному.Слышал что помогает функция gets,чтобы избежать этого и хоть млрд букв вводи в char будет помещаться сколько угодно!Помогите разобраться(примеры).

Comment: gets не занимается выделением памяти и будет ровно та же проблема. Вариант решения - получать каждый раз один символ и добавлять его к std::string. Примеры и документация, кстати, ищутся в гугле.

Comment: Владимир абсолютно прав в том, что `gets` не контролирует размер выделенного буфера под строку. Как альтернативу его способу, можно предложить использавать `fgets`. Примеры использования и описание: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ (Да, и std::string к C все же отношения не имеет)

Comment: Это   Язык Си или С++?

Comment: @andy.37 fgets тоже не выделяет память, но хотя бы при грамотном использовании не даст переполнить буфер...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, изначально о выделении памяти речь не шла вроде... Кстати, интересная задачка - написать аналог `gets` динамически выделяющий память под строку (только не посимвольно, конечно, а то слишком уж накладно выйдет) - не тривиальноя, но и не очень уж сложная.

Comment: @andy.37 да все просто как раз: malloc на старте, хранится размер буфера. И в случае если он кончается - выделять в два раза больше и переносить содержимое.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, функция `gets` уже не поддерживается стандартом C, так как она небезопасная. Вместо нее лучше использовать функцию `fgets`, хотя поведение этих функций не идентично, так как функция `fgets` также заносит в строку символ новой строки, если он вмещается. Также можно использовать функцию `scanf` , указав число считываемых символов.

Язык C не имеет стандартных контейнеров, которые могут динамически менять свой размер. Поэтому в любом случае вам придется использовать символьный массив фиксированного размера и туда считывать данные.

Вы можете распределить этот массив динамически и переопределять его по мере необходимости, используя функцию `realloc` совместно с функцией `fgets` или `scanf`.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, С99 еще поддерживает `gets`, хотя она и признана deprecated.

Comment: @andy.37 C99 уже устарел. В C11 `gets` убрали: `removed the gets function (<stdio.h>)`